# Highcharts sets default value for blank data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to set/supply value (default to 0) for blank data in hours as shown in attached image below.

The target result should have all graphs even for blank hours.

[image]

Comment: Hi @aldrien.h, Could you provide us with your chart configuration object?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek please help to check my script here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729943/highcharts-set-xaxis-values-starting-12am-and-ends-in-11pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a loop and add points to your data array with some default `y` value (50 in the example below) and `x` value with the same interval as `tickInterval`:

```
var data = [
        [1561593600000, 102.5],
        [1561658400000, 177.45],
        [1561723200000, 115.5]
    ],
    interval = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    j = 1,
    i = data[0][0] + interval;

for (j; j < data.length; j++) {
    for (i; i < data[j][0]; i += interval) {
        data.push([i, 50])
    }
    i += interval;
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{
        data: data.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a[0] - b[0]
        })
    }],

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: interval
    },
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m0zfeyd4/